# Display land use categories in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a raster data in TIFF format which represents land use categories (urban, forest, agriculture etc). This I made in ArcGIS where it is possible to see all categories in different unique colors but I can't see those categories when I opened that file in QGIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically style raster using unique values in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190470/automatically-style-raster-using-unique-values-in-qgis). For setting symbology of categories manually look here: [Qgis: style a discrete raster](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194116/qgis-style-a-discrete-raster).